# How to use Keycloak JAVA API with keycloak-spring-boot-starter package

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, keycloak

I have used the Keycloak spring boot adapter for my spring boot server and I am able to get my user authenticated. But when i want to get user data like the groups he is in, I am unable to get that data through the KeycloakPrinciple object I get to access through the request. I am however able to get the ID of the user and I though it would be straight forward to access the user profile in the spring boot application as it has the keycloak adapter. Any idea as to how to get that data or if I should add or do something else?

**pom.xml**

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20210307</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>-->
<!--            <scope>test</scope>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot-admin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
                <version>12.0.4</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

**applications.yaml**

```
server:
  port: 9000

keycloak:
  auth-server-url: http://localhost:8080/auth
  realm: test
  resource: spring-boot-client
  credentials:
    secret: 41e7abe2-35a4-46c0-ba68-40dd16080b1a
  bearer-only: true
  public-client: true
  securityConstraints:
    - authRoles:
        - CANDIDATE
        - AUTHOR
        - ADMIN
      securityCollections:
        - name: ping
          patterns:
            - /ping
    - authRoles:
        - AUTHOR
        - ADMINN
      securityCollections:
        - name: Author
          patterns:
            - /author

logging:
  level:
    org.keycloak: TRACE
```

**How i am accessing the ID of the user making the request to the spring boot server**

```
@GetMapping("/ping")
    public ResponseEntity<String> ping(KeycloakPrincipal<KeycloakSecurityContext> principal) {
        String user_id = principal.getKeycloakSecurityContext().getToken().getSubject();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(user_id);
    }
```

Any guidance would be of help as I looked through all the documentation I could get my hands on. Yes keycloak does provide a JavaDoc which I did refer and also an ADMIN REST API, which I thought would be a bad way to access this data(I might be wrong). I want to know if just using the starter adapter would not give me access to the Java API, cause I can only access the KeycloakPrinciple.

Answer (score 0):

Why should the Rest API be a bad way to get user specific Data?
You can configure a specific client with a Client Secret and minimal realm roles to get the data you need.
Did you have a Look at the token? Is the Information you need already in the token?

You can get Data Like realm roles token.getOtherClaims
https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/10.0/javadocs/org/keycloak/representations/AccessTokenResponse.html

You have to make sure that the Information you mapped is in the token. Therefore have a Look a the admin console -> clients -> your Client -> mappers -> evaluate

Maybe you can Post a few Pictures of your current configuration